# Make code acting on an outlet reusable among view controllers

Tags: ios, objective-c, viewcontroller

Suppose there are multiple view controllers and that each one has a outlet.  Now I want to do exactly the same thing to each outlet. Since the outlets each link to a particular view controller, I cannot use sub-classing to move a code block into its super class. Is there any method to reuse the code in such a circumstance?

Comment: of course you can move it in a super class. just define the outlet in the super class. connect it in all the viewControllers in the storyboard and write the code acting on the outlet in the super class. I have done exactly that already to specify the behaviour of a back button present in a multitude of my views.

Comment: Do you mean I just need to declare an outlet with the same name, and then even what the UI connects to the subclass view controller, it will still works?

Comment: Yes. Just specify the outlet in the super class. You will see that you can connect to it in the interface builder, if you set the owner of a view to a subclass of said super class. That is already an indication that you did the setup correctly. And then all you do is let the super class handle the outlet

Comment: Oh I get it, what you meant is to directly connect the superclass 'so outlet to storyboard.

Comment: Did you already try it? Does it work?

Comment: @luk2302 I just came up with this question but I cannot try it now, I will try it maybe half a day later.

Comment: @luk2302 thank you in advance, I think it will work. It is really cool view controller's superclass can also hold outlet.